# two sockets (one is async) for mDNS tests

Tags: c#, sockets, mdns

I make some mDNS tests and I use two sockets: one to send mDNS requests and one to sniff the network (this one is async). Sometimes I see answers which are not received by the requesting socket simply because the destination address is 224.0.0.251. The thing is that when the sync socket times out, the async socket receives the sniffed data only after the timeout of the other one expires. Why is that? Thanks.

For requests I have the FindIP() function and for sniffing I have the ClassSniffer class. See the code below.

```
    private void FindIP( int idx_target )
    {
        string TargetName = textBox_Name_array[ idx_target ].Text.Trim();
        string TargetSuffix = "local";
        if( TargetName.Length > 0xFF ) TargetName = TargetName.Substring( 0, 0xFF );

        Socket sock = new Socket( AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp );
        sock.SendTimeout = 3000;
        sock.ReceiveTimeout = Convert.ToInt32( numericUpDown_RxTimeOut.Value ) * 1000;

        IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint( IPAddress.Parse( mDNS_addr ), mDNS_port );

        byte[] buffer_send, buffer_recv = new byte[ 1024 ];

        buffer_send = new byte[ 0 ]
        .Concat( BitConverter.GetBytes( cnt_trans ).Take( 2 ).Reverse().ToArray() ) // Transaction ID
        .Concat( BitConverter.GetBytes(     0     ).Take( 2 ).Reverse().ToArray() ) // Flags
        .Concat( BitConverter.GetBytes(     1     ).Take( 2 ).Reverse().ToArray() ) // Number of questions
        .Concat( BitConverter.GetBytes(     0     ).Take( 2 ).Reverse().ToArray() ) // Number of answers
        .Concat( BitConverter.GetBytes(     0     ).Take( 2 ).Reverse().ToArray() ) // Number of authority resource records
        .Concat( BitConverter.GetBytes(     0     ).Take( 2 ).Reverse().ToArray() ) // Number of additional resource records
        .Concat( new byte[] { Convert.ToByte( TargetName.Length   ) } ).Concat( Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( TargetName   ) )
        .Concat( new byte[] { Convert.ToByte( TargetSuffix.Length ) } ).Concat( Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( TargetSuffix ) )
        .Concat( new byte[] { 0 } ) // Terminator
        .Concat( BitConverter.GetBytes(     1     ).Take( 2 ).Reverse().ToArray() ) // Type (A record)
        .Concat( BitConverter.GetBytes(     1     ).Take( 2 ).Reverse().ToArray() ) // Class IN
        .ToArray();
        // TX
        sock.SendTo( buffer_send, endPoint );
        // RX
        try
        {
            sock.Receive( buffer_recv );
            ...
        }
        ...
    }

    private class ClassSniffer
    {
        public ClassSniffer( Form_Main main_instance )
        {
            this.main_instance = main_instance;
            buff_data = new byte[ 1024 ];
            recv_done = false;
            timer_socket = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timer_socket.SynchronizingObject = main_instance;
            timer_socket.Elapsed += TimerAttenElapsed;
            timer_socket.Interval = 100;
            timer_socket.Start();

            sock_conn = new Socket( AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp );
            sock_conn.SetSocketOption( SocketOptionLevel.Udp, SocketOptionName.NoDelay, 1 );
            sock_conn.SetSocketOption( SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, 1 );
            sock_conn.Bind( new IPEndPoint( IPAddress.Any, Form_Main.mDNS_port ) );
            sock_conn.SetSocketOption( SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.MulticastTimeToLive, 0 ); // 0
            sock_conn.SetSocketOption( SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership
                                     , new MulticastOption( IPAddress.Parse( Form_Main.mDNS_addr ) ) );
            SnifferRecieve();
        }
        private Form_Main main_instance;
        private System.Timers.Timer timer_socket;
        private Mutex socket_mutex = new Mutex();
        private Socket sock_conn;
        private byte[] buff_data = new byte[ 1024 ];
        private int recv_size = 0;
        private bool recv_done = false;

        private void SnifferRecieve()
        {
            try
            {
                IPEndPoint LocalIPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint( IPAddress.Any, Form_Main.mDNS_port );
                EndPoint LocalEndPoint = (EndPoint)LocalIPEndPoint;
                StateObject state = new StateObject();
                state.socket_work = sock_conn;
                sock_conn.BeginReceiveFrom( state.buffer, 0, state.buffer.Length, 0, ref LocalEndPoint, new AsyncCallback( SnifferReceiveCallback ), state );
            }
            catch( Exception excp )
            {
                string err_msg = excp.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void SnifferReceiveCallback( IAsyncResult async_res )
        {
            IPEndPoint LocalIPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint( IPAddress.Any, Form_Main.mDNS_port );
            EndPoint LocalEndPoint = (EndPoint)LocalIPEndPoint;
            StateObject async_state = (StateObject)async_res.AsyncState;
            Socket socket_client = async_state.socket_work;
            int async_recv_size = socket_client.EndReceiveFrom( async_res, ref LocalEndPoint );
            socket_client.BeginReceiveFrom( async_state.buffer, 0, async_state.buffer.Length, 0, ref LocalEndPoint
                                          , new AsyncCallback( SnifferReceiveCallback ), async_state );
            socket_mutex.WaitOne();
            recv_size = async_recv_size;
            async_state.buffer.CopyTo( buff_data, 0 );
            recv_done = true;
            socket_mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }

        private void TimerAttenElapsed( object source, ElapsedEventArgs e )
        {
            socket_mutex.WaitOne();
            if( recv_done )
            {
                main_instance.SnifferWriteData( buff_data, recv_size ); // displays data in a textBox
                recv_done = false;
            }
            socket_mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize it is a trivial problem: not the receiving but only showing the sniffing is delayed and this is because it is done on timer event in the main thread which is blocked by the timeout of the requesting socket.